# How can you use the Excel VBA function "AverageIf" with a variant array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a variant array with a variety of values.

For example let's say they are the following:
1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0

I want to take an average of that array, however I want to ignore the zeroes.

My problem is that the "WorksheetFunction.AverageIf()" function can only use ranges.

I have found countless help converting a range into a variant array, but nothing on converting a variant array into a range.

Answer (score 1):

since it is already an array it will be quicker just to loop the array and sum the values and divide by the number of items in the array above `0`:

```
Sub lkjlkj()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    
    Dim sm As Double
    sm = 0#
    
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 0
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) > 0 Then
            sm = sm + arr(i)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim avg As Double
    avg = sm / cnt
    
    Debug.Print avg
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't drop into my code very well, after a few minutes of debugging, I couldn't get it to work. I ended up just utilizing the values in the original range and building a sum (See my "answer" below....mind you it's a poorly written chunk of code, I'm new-ish)

Answer (score 1):

**A simple alternative**

Via boundary count and negative filtering you could count the non-zero items and divide the array sum by this divisor:

```
Sub TestAverage()
    Dim a: a = Array(1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    dim avg as Double: avg = Application.Sum(a) / (UBound(Filter(a, 0, False)) + 1)
    Debug.Print avg
End Sub
```

**Caveat//Edit**: `Filter` gets *any* **partial** finding, so searching `0` would also find `10` or `20`. A refined function based on counting the items in `Application.Match()` - *c.f. @VBasic2008 's solution* - applied on the given array as first argument and `Array(0)` as 2nd argument gets waterproof results. Hint: `Application.Count()` omits error values, so you avoid a further loop.

```
Function AvgWithoutZeros(arr1D As Variant) As Double
With Application
    Dim n: n = .Count(arr1D) - .Count(.Match(arr1D, Array(0), 0))  ' number of non-zero items
    AvgWithoutZeros = .Sum(arr1D) / n
End With
End Function
```

**Example calls**

```
Sub TestAverageOfArrayValues()
    Dim a: a = Array(1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print AvgWithoutZeros(a)
End Sub
```

Just to demonstrate some array conversions based on a given range (e.g. column A):

```
Sub HowToConvertRangeTo1DimArray()
    With Sheet1                ' Code(Name) of your worksheet
        Dim lastRow As Long:  lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Dim rng     As Range: Set rng = .Range("A2:D" & lastRow) ' start e.g. in row 2
    End With
    
    Dim arr2Dim: arr2Dim = rng.Value                        ' assign data to 2-dim array
    Dim arr1Dim: arr1Dim = Application.Transpose(arr2Dim)   ' make array "flat"
    Debug.Print AvgWithoutZeros(arr1Dim)
End Sub
```

Comment: Elegant Solution, unfortunately my code is already slapped together with my makeshift solution above. I have yet to successfully attempt sub functions within my function modules.

Comment: Well, you did it again. Nice. BTW, my solution allows multiple `Exceptions` (as I call them). Is there a way to spread your `elegance` (as OP calls it) to it?

Answer (score 1):

### Average With Exceptions

This one uses a combination of `Application.Sum` and `Application.Match`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getAvgWithExceptions()
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = Array(1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Dim Exceptions As Variant: Exceptions = Array(0)
    
    Debug.Print getAverage(Data, Exceptions)

End Sub

Function getAverage(Data As Variant, Exceptions As Variant) As Double
    Dim DataSum As Double: DataSum = Application.Sum(Data)
    Dim DataCount As Long: DataCount = count1D(Data, Exceptions)
    getAverage = DataSum / DataCount
End Function

Function count1D(Data As Variant, Exceptions As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
        If IsError(Application.Match(Data(i), Exceptions, 0)) Then
            count1D = count1D + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: A valid+ solution with some *"overkill"* for this special question, but worth studying (plus some explanations) as many readers won't know that you can use `Application.Match()` the shown way.

Comment: Elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

Ranges are defined within the spreadsheet as the function I was originally trying to use requires the use of values in the spreadsheet. Nobody could figure out a way to use the "AverageIf" function simply because they would have to change the spreadsheet itself, forcing values into areas that may already be populated.

The better solution is to simply build an averaging function with an if-statement within it. My particular problem was to only average values that are not zero.

Here is that code:

```
Public Function AvgIf(rng As Range)
'Declaring Variables
Dim array1() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim Xdim As Integer
Dim Ydim As Integer
Dim temp1 As Integer
Dim temp2 As Integer

'In this example, the array is user-defined by the input range
array1 = rng.Value

'Find Array Size
Xdim = UBound(array1, 1)
Ydim = UBound(array1, 2)

'Cycling through every cell of the array
For i = 1 To (Xdim)
For ii = 1 To (Ydim)

'Insert If Statement Here (You can change it to be whatever you want)
If array1(i, ii) > 0 Then
temp1 = temp1 + array1(i, ii)
temp2 = temp2 + 1
End If

Next ii
Next i

'Cheating by doing the last calculation in the output
AvgIf = temp1 / temp2

End Function
```

That is what you should ideally use instead of forcing data into your spreadsheet.

Alternatively, if your problem is similar to mine (array is just a copy of a range), you can follow the below information:

Since my range was converted into an array, I simply used the original range to solve the issue. (See below for code)

```
Public Function TempAvg(rng as Range)

Dim i as integer
Dim t1 as Double
Dim t2 as Double

For i = 1 to 20

If rng(i) > 0 Then t1 = t1 + rng(i)
If rng(1) > 0 Then t2 = t2 + 1

Next i

TempAvg = t1 / t2

End Function
```

That fixed my issues. I apologize to all those posting elegant solutions as I can't seem to get them to work in the scope of my project. I'm sure it's something I've messed up, not their code. Please read the other answers for possibly better solutions.

Comment: (1) You start saying "I have a variant array with a variety of values." and mention "My problem is that the `WorksheetFunction.AverageIf()` function can only use ranges". So it's natural to assume you wanted to execute code upon the *variant array* and not upon a range you don't know how to convert from the initial array (btw there are numerous examples at SO). (2) What's the problem to get the valid answers here *"to work* in the scope of your project"*?

Comment: I'll bet the problem implementing other people's code is that you have a 2-d array and their examples are for 1-d arrays. If you make an array like `vaRng = Range(...).Values` you end up with 2-d (rows and columns, even if your range is only one row or column). If you want to go back and take a stab at their code, you'd have to refer to your array as `MyArray(i,1)` to, for instance, get the first value of a 1-column range converted to a 2-d array. But if your solution works, it would only be for educational purposes.

Comment: Dick, thanks for the pointers, I'll see if that helps.Turns out my array had multiple rows, not columns. Oof, once again I'm new to this.

TM, I fully explained that in the post-script below the code. This is my solution for my application, it is not "THE" solution. I just posted it in case others have the same specific issue.